# Move directory in DOS (batch file) without knowing full directory name

Tags: batch-file

In Bash I can move a directory without know the full directory name like so:

`mv gradle-*/ gradle/`

How do I do this in `cmd` (i.e. batch file, not powershell).

The `move` command doesn't seem to allow this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MOVE only moves 1 dir to another location and therefore doesn't bother expanding wildcards.
Unlike Unix where the shell expands wildcards on Windows each command has to do it by itself which leads to all sorts of differing behaviour between commands.

You can use the FOR command to simulate this.

FOR in it's various variants behaves somewhat like "find . -name "wildcard" -exec {} "   on Unix.

```
FOR /d %%i IN (gradle-*) DO move %%i gradle\%%i
```

Comment: Works! Thx ..  I had to remove the last %%i in your example

Comment: Wasn't to sure about it myself if that would be correct syntax. But I didn't have a Windows box in the vicinity to test at the time so I had to go from memory.